# ASP.NET Custom Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I am trying to bind **Panel.visible** to be visible depending on matching database table field and querystring as:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Visible='<%# Eval("Mjr_Id") == Request.QueryString["Mjr_Id"] %>'> ... </asp:Panel>
```

But it failed, do you have idea about the correct binding format to do this?

Comment: post your code ,not getting your problem

Comment: It failed: what is the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Eval function returns an object, whereas the QueryString indexer returns a string. Applying the equality operator to an object and a string will result in a reference comparison, whereas you want a value comparison.

To make the code work, you'll need to convert the object to a string:

```
Visible='<%# Eval("Mjr_Id", "{0}") == Request.QueryString["Mjr_Id"] %>'
```

**NB:** This will perform a case-sensitive ordinal comparison. If that's not what you want, you'll need to use the *string.Equals(string, string, StringComparison)* method.